# Wick's time ordering operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, time, definition

I am working on Wolfgang Nolting's . And I feel confused about the time ordering operator.Below is how he introduced the Wick's time ordering operator.

[image]

My understanding is that the $\epsilon$ in the defining equation is artificial, so what ever the choice $AB$ is, we can choose whatever $\epsilon$ as long as we like it (though sometimes it is convenient to choose - for fermionic operators, and + for bosonic operators). And I understand that $AB$ as arbitrary operator, it is not necessary that $A$ is a single creation/annilation operator, and same for $B$.

In Chapter 5, when he tried to develop the perturbation theory, he argued something like this. He argued that $V$ contains an even number of fermionic operators, so the replacement is always permitted. Why?

[image]

This is where he tried to make the replacement. This is a time evolution operator. And $T_D$ is the normal time-ordering operator, i.e. when you order everything, there won't be the $\epsilon$ factor as in the (3.125) in the first picture.
I understand my description here is not adequate, because there are many equations I didn't put here. So if anyone can have a look at Wolfgang's book, that will be most helpful.

[image]

Comment: This seems to a very convoluted way to say that bosons commute and fermions anticommute. But what exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is that why can you replace dyson's time ordering operator by Wick's time ordering operator. Like in Wick time ordering operator, you will have terms like -V(t2)V(t1),with the minus sign,when t2>t1 but if we employ Dyson's time ordering operator, we won't have the minus sign.

Comment: Actually I have consulted Coleman's many body physics books. In his book, there seems to be only one type of time ordering operator, whose effect depends upon the odd/even numbers of ferminonic operators involved. But in Nolting's books, there are two types of time-ordering operators.

Comment: Indeed, it's been a long time ago that I studied this but I seem to remember that it is always understood that you get a minus sign when you exchange two fermions in time ordering. Having a quick look at some of Nolting's books, it seems like he often sacrifices clarity for exactitude. That can be confusing at times.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the time-ordering operator? Are there two kinds of time ordering operator or is there only one?(like the one we used in developing the time-evolution operator in Schrodinger equation for time-dependent operator) And what is the time ordering operator used in defining the so-called "Causal Green's function"?

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. They are the same thing.